# Python and Sublime text related query

Tags: python, sublimetext3

I was trying to build a new system in Sublime Text that can build code with Python. But I was wondering if we need Python 3 separately installed as well?

Also where can I install packages like PyPDF2 directly: into Sublime Text or in Python shell or in terminal (Mac user)?

Answer (score 2):

Sublime text is just a text editor, it doesn't come with any compiler or interpreted included, it runs them for you, so you would need to install Python 3 if you are going to code in it, you can install it in you machine with [Homebrew](https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-and-Python), in case that you don't have Homebrew you can install it pasting this in the terminal:

```sh
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

and then

```
brew install python
```

You can follow these [instructions](https://docs.python-guide.org/starting/install3/osx/) for more details.

Then if you want to build python3 in sublime text you can use the sublime text packages [Python 3](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Python%203) or [Anaconda](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Anaconda), which you can install through [packagecontrol](https://packagecontrol.io).
In case that you haven't installed packagecontrol yet you can find the instructions [here](https://packagecontrol.io/installation), it's very simple, open sublime text, hit `cmd+shift+p`, type `Install Package Control`, and `enter`.

With some tricks you can install packages from sublime text, but I would not recommend it when doing it from the terminal is so simple, just using `pip` or `pip3` for python 3, for example `pip3 install PyPDF2`, you can search for python packages at the [Python Package Index](https://pypi.org).